# ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (/myip-address:9096) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, handshake

I have a distributed kafka with 3 brokers that have port numbers 9093, 9094, 9095 and I added the SSL with port numbers 9096, 9097, 9098.
I am getting the following error when I run the producer client:
[2020-06-15 10:08:07,892] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (/myip-address:9096) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-06-15 10:08:07,893] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker myip-address:9096 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

I have tried to use: ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm= but that did not solve the problem for me.
I am using Kafka 2.5
I can share my config files if need be.

What else could I try to troubleshoot this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by simply using my 
     domain-name:9096,domain-name:9097,domain-name:9098 
instead of:
     my-ip-address:9096,my-ip-address:9097,my-ip-address:9098

So, using the actual domain name is important due to the certificate being created with the domain name.